# Unable to read gzip encoded in using HttpClientInterface in Symfony Project

Tags: php, symfony, curl, gzip, symfony-http-client

I'm unable to read gzip encoded response in a Symfony projet. Here is my service :

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class myApi
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function getApiContent(){
        $headers =  [
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            ];
        $response = $this->client->request('GET', 'https://www.google.com', [
            'headers' => $headers,
        ]);
        $content = $response->getContent();
        dd($content);
    }
}
```

Here is my response :

```
b"\x1Fï\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02 ┼[ÙzøHô■ƒ½└d?[zî$@'$é│\x1EÃë3╔õõdrÜ|~\x1Ah\tb\x04\x18Ée[Í¢ýÑýÕý▄┼¥ı\x1CädgfvµÃ~┘æÚSu\x1DÌ««Û¯}┤ÒFNv\x1Ds╔╦f┴┴#·ò³î¤R'è╣%╦ó@\x1D,┘╦▓x▄ÚñÄÃg¼\x1D%Ë╬Gn┐aS.K\x01\vºû<IZO¥╚ ┬Ö{­hã3&9Qÿ±0│õî_e\x1DónJÄÃÆögÍç¸O[å,\x11┘\x16┐ÿ¹ùû|öwo¢Ãä‗6ëÄ?├diÃNXÞ·ß┤3ìói└º\x1DÝ¬³<K3┤▒─=só J╬4¦pÒv\x1CNs9Ô$è-YÉ\x01§╠¤\x02~­Lî|È╔KÅR'±ÒLúðü╚W·ÚõõÚ┼îƒ>²³ô±t\x10¢\x1F:ƒ\x0F-K>hLµíô¨QÏh.\x17~ÞFïv╬âÁ<?~>Ì{‗µØ■¨¨D?¨<\x7F\x1D,N§╦/ºÐÐbO9?■¶\x06═¬óuU¢ÎSòÐ@Ú\x0FîaW\x19§{J_S¹è«\x0E\x14m02ö«å/¢½ö«ÐU¶\x1Ezb\x18uË¹ áÚz\x1FmÜÌıQ\x180XÐz#Ñ;Êò^WÚÛã¿ºüñ«¸@OË­;ý§z4Éµı\fC1║FOÚ\x19}\x03t\x07║2ÊG¬\x02¥FènhÿkD#u\x03Tz¬Ä!CC\x19Þ=]\x01s`L\x05'\x03Øµ\x1Eó\x03:+â^ùXÞÙåÊÙkCE\x1F\x0Eçÿ\x08õ­Ñ`:\x087È4EÙÅ║ <\x1C)Ü┌\x13\x04TÑ▀═╣Î4Á½\x18`É\x08h}ó\x0F÷zÜ¬Ô\x07LÞ¬Ä▒├nùdýÙÿY\x1F@f\x1A¡\e║b\fötêð#\x06ð¿\fò~\x7F4R\x06├~_Ú½ð¸ð\x18\x0Eö\x1Eä┼¶ðrO\x05ô°Ç³ÉT\x1F@Qzw4Tå=░ııç}\x05╩ýæ%0çÐÝ+¢\x01Ú\x05╝é¼¬\fG\x10KCƒ\x1EL\x06µUÛ\x08\x12ÈGıH║\x1E!\x1D\x0FGáo@÷^\x1Fs¸┴OO\x1DðD¦\x1EL,öìyÁa\x1FÍª\x01=ØdÈ\fÞP\x07J╚tPf\x17ô\x19ð=\f\x05Ûz_ÿ\x1AÜı\x05Ò\x00ðák\x10{└I\x1FvÛ\x0F1Yo\x08æ\x07\x03¶"n║\x03Ó\x03G\t@ÓË@`D©Ëáy(\x0E°é╩└Ó!öâI·ðÄF\x16#y└\x1F\x06i─7┤▄º?\x06:wI\x14m\x04"\x03░¡Ú\x03┬)8ÐI> \x13xÝ\x01«²¥N¼Bt`\x16ð\x00▄®ÅÍ\x1DæîärU\x03\x1A╗dô!Ï\x05®~\x0E \x01§Ù\x01║└\e\x08\x02s\x1A¡\x18░▄\e\x11║\x08AñË~\x1F3\x01ù\x03L½®:Y\x17(#AÐ┴ E(Cb\x12\x18ü*\x05ni┼\t1\x15!'¼ï1È2ñÕüv\x02þ└\x10XÞv╔ÆÓ\x08ýðÌ\x05╬\x00Ð¥bÞ┤¬·äiâ¼½ÉÊ└\x1F1AåÛbN`\x16(ýb4 Ïº5N°┴jÞÆpdû.ÖB%╚á\x01T¹]▒\x0Eí\x05ì©\x11(!Éð?`m\x04aì!i\x07]\x07\x000ëb\x10z¹dF¼4"\x04Ø\x03░P\x02\x08\x18¬:\x00=\x03┌\x11.\x01ä\fòñ\x1Eé3¿×\x08¸¹ñàaÅ└ä┐#ó>█ï1\x1AÚí½c\x0EúGM░7Ö¬O\x10é╩ådÚ×\x02|A┼deò>¬\x7FF±\x17└çZ┴\x0Eëö3ú\t┘`T±EjA\x07àû\x7F\x17┬j─$ »\x02(Ë╩´\x0EzÿH\x1F\x10\x18{õd║b=k┬¯X|p╝?¢\x1C´\x1D■¬┐Ì[Ö╣ºnºíÁÀÓÂ\x17´ò5þ'/¡=▒ìÝÖ½fúiÍ¦³âKûH\x13┼│¥~3╦jÚ╝┴Ü╦Iö4¿Ð6┘¯ncçÁº<;╠▓─Àþ\x19┐¢¦iÏÍf]Cµ¥+7øM│╔ð\x14│\x04;▄½╚Õf┬│y\x12J÷ÝÝdUM\x12lLbà¾ °Ù3\x05\x7F6ıÛA5Ð¼┴\x14[q\x14WÖ6ù4\x19à\x00ªs{█Êv,╗Ørû8^CÌÕ¥%7oo\eh\x16▀¹þÀ®┤4½Ì)\x10¢└ªk\x05hª/¥o\x15§¹¿0]ó¥Òý¯\x16;ÞÖôz¥╗╗╗EHÈRr\x1Ax‗Ä┼\x04Ð¬a\x7FcxËt,p,wõ²ã\x14\x7Fº<<├"æø¹‗cåHã‗w\x1DD\x13¹l\x1F\x04\x18À¸9¥o«­¨äe╝\x1DFïFs▀5; ╬C\x1E┐Ø±4k8─\x00ıñc┘▓è9â╚añ║6bï,BÈ\x01Í0═­]}6Äô\x04\x06öÖ▄Tv4eÖ&╬ÏQª┴l6ÍVM┼ü&ÜÑE£ò9▒JD\x1E?/┴\t│\x1E?À╬k┼ù(\x07f5çU\x03kAèáRß=êªÙ.5C¹ôåcıM▀\2+õ\vÚ9EJfÄ\x03»\x1D­pÜyª¸ò\x7F│ÿë\x080õ$ôE_A\x04MÊ\x07│ú$½3Ô‗Çg\x08/1jàAÉ█rVuû>$ü5├jk;,\x08\x1AÖþºø╦«Þym-Î\v¸ÜÍ`Q©┌ÉIH├Ü─│\x03å|ÎõA╩ùnäÔ/,¾┌\x14<F3,Ýàþ\x07╝┤ı§Wþ[sU+X_Aý[aæ\x1Dm=u}║è╣¶║\x1D¤S\x0F5k╔f5\x1Ecö¯\x19\x16╠─░6ïÒÓ║QU*u2\x1752B╦ø\x16\Ë║╚Y°·ò}úåo5\x1A\x18v\x18\x04[z┌\x1EG‗«ÃÏWÍÄV\x11©¬[tÁe¼óËä\f┤ß/æZ╠g­6Ý‗Ò8Óó╠\¸°\x12\x1F/²\x14í=Ã▓Hþ÷╠¤dÑ\x1Anþ■çÖdN8âî%\x00|^Ú▄±q.╦X+º1a░7Í\x12│d╦ö<┴\x05²¦¦àÀõ9\x03i¹ó}╔é9\x7F╝úÄa\éê─H`‗,6Í2'÷×­\tø\x07Yú®└\x19eQ³\x06Ú\x03ø▓\╝µJ┘Qß┬■║îNÓ;þ¸ë╚ã┬╣»┼$6ÏÄ§#┌µ┌æ\x175MhI>äÿ\f\x14ª»ÏîË\x12\x16©WUaõ%|\x02-┘\tgþ\x12[æ­+╠zW÷\╠Mï?Ûõi\x12ÊÑý\x1AYË├®═\x12Õßt×‗\x04ó üK²\e>Í║±ò\x19C\x11HÍZð▀Xï»ñ\x1D\x7F\x16├E0ê▒\x12Òû\x1E¸º^6Í§°jUð(\x07┘QûE│±ps\x1CÕÆ-\x16°Ëp£ððU{j{~▄%╝Å╦ôj▓4|WzÞî▄ßD3k£a*\x1AT╬¡Üqö·dò1│1\x08Ü2ëåÌâ\x04\v▀═╝1ó╗\x7F¡■sã]ƒIð─\x12├Á:Ùµ\fª¾├ûÓh▄¯¾Öy╔ô╠ç┌^A░Éxé\x15Öì\x03>╔V+Fä\x14·Ý-à`.wóDÇl<\x0F!LÓç╝&²ã\x00æÕÄ\x1F¬¬S´ü&_¬À╗«┴§ßVù╔Fùæ¬Í█\x1F└─┬┤ààÝ╚¢V2WaJ¼┤¢▄ã\x136¾âÙ1K|\x16()\vË\x16LþOVÈwÖk\x03èìá\x05╚╗h]Å\x01Ü\x08█Ð├i4--<\x06D$\x03 ®½╠]Æ¿¡Bºmâ¤└&s╬fÊVô\x06<¼░bf┼,%Ltò╠Ûò"!\x0E5▄┴è¤rv\x17¨`;▄\x02\t$┘8\x04\x1D\x16¼┌AÜUµýWVGá.áÆN|Etíæcì8¥#7§Jï\x0E├{;©ÚÊ§Ë8`Îc?\x14\x12┘Ðò╣]àÉÔ╝@ôPÅ*§Í­"ðîQ^¨a<¤6\fßç\x1Eª╔r²█╠9ƒ&\x11\x104~8ÖL╠)ÛèòÛ┘Üã\fs\eu!6÷\x15\e{d9àì\x19╝ı% 16WÝI ▒-Ñ│±ÑÅ\x05┼¦═╣VÝÈ\x0E£e¦'¶I┐T\v\x1AÑ&6Táô6─\x17~ÑÂÿ┼j\x0ER█Ìö┌ÿî&╠╠=┬8¸\x04ÞYT┤╩Ñ┴\ç½Ê├í:ý\x0F┘·o^o\x16êÞ¬ı\x14\e<«\x1E~╝x{°╩«±~ƒ\x15UIË\v\x02u\x16þIð(\x0FÁBvyå`(Ê§\x11ØW5a§û> \x1Fû­ÿ│¼U2.╠S3ºÚ╠ô\x14▀qõç\x19OÛ\x1CøÙE8¤ê+|Õ­ý▀\x03¤¹▄\x15q\\x02á«█\;bÐî'Ï£Êe9â\x00O;¾ÖÀ,VP\x1FïeÁv'\x7F±|m¢┼t‗ÒDBÁdOàÓûLÿû Ìi\x1DÝ╣\x14à¯²@§{"Ó§yè`Öbë§\x16O,\x14▒«dIw\x0F\x00CiwW*┐\x11a·\x13®Q╬'k.½©║Ð\x14┴0■3W\x0F¿Ù\x0E═ëÇ╣\x1C1┘¦]\x7F#b\x11ènÈBÄ®}Q´C┼ZÀı\x03³ú\x1Cv¡JÎ┐ö(aÜàS[«è┤%\x1D<#\e┐Âõ\x04,MQº\x1D╝Ò\x0E\x1C■{È▒\x0FñGl¦$Q¶`\x15╣Pº│Xöçƒm¸\x06ZØz±c\x0Fßf▓ø1\eëÆ| \x04N\x1FuÏ\x1FÊÖ▒8¡\x11óbØN \x1F³é¬?úB½░ñÔD│NØä!\x1F╝A¾ƒæ ü«üÞ╣]Éÿ\x06Íô/9\tM>°\x1C═▀úÚ¤¿└ÊÚ\x06#b|(\x1F\x1C:┘\x1Ck,¹²/h─\x0FÛ$¿\ðÖ╔\x07¤¿°g$▄\x04ï¸.\eæ|­äZ¯\x0E\x17\v5?░▀Ì\x15õ?6|ÿ\x05ØIÊA8¤:╚ç¦╣ôÑ¨t\x1EÓ6ç¯þ\x10y~ Ý&ýb\x1EÖ4¨úNÄ╝\x0Eð©å$EüÆp \x16\x05^%<Ëÿà9d├ècƒ|\x05ÛÙ¡ô¬urO+»ÛXMá;‗ È═óõ║\x13┼\x19\x04╩a$Wä{\x07'ó¦┐ÿsÚ#Àà"oIò\x05MhÇO8étçºw\x07┐a\tø²Oû\x14½B\f╠â\x7FÙ\f×7g¶l¿ni£9\x0E<pÂü½S×\·\x0E\x7F\x19┴Î\x17`Å1îke╔£´Ê\x05è\x1F╬æ┬▀5\eì▀ÕÄ§ý­╦ßß█:âGQ\x18‗+X■~#ò\x1D¢\x02/bcV ¿G\x1E\x18W]‗_çËª\x05┐â¼.Ó\f×\x1D▒Á,£T0ì¦ÁôBæí\x04þéÞ;│õ³┌\x06Ç\x14█Ø%ÅtYx§\x1F¦\x12æâ__\x14QÚlß!@9[ok┼Øæ>È»FzymT¼å2\ıE¼*iê└õ\x02ƒ2\x06õ\x1C{1ÐòIÜ³┐\FèT%&÷░ùƒj╔Rê$═Æi\x13├\x02\t©õ­ (f▒dU\x16eÇÈ)╩ÞûHùbgã┌îb¬p+\x0E· Æ\x0FvC;ì▒ñ2W4\x15]s\x05c║hæ░ÏÆIç\x149\x16¾¹Pí╚ä-¨¨ÚÙûa¶G-Mûè\v?▀uyXì(·ÕÀ|┼x/°Aþ╝9ìµë├À║öä╝x½ÀÝ/■ÉÜÝ{w┌ÎHô¦┤2W\x19\x04¡¾2èÖ%Á\x18P\x1AÁ╠¨\x12\x1E0èq╠ø\x08iäVM[\x10Fö#QDSæ»Ô¬\x12\x16²2ïæÉ.▄\x13HıÒÁ2°═ÎCÎ $▒9Ø\x1D╬b:*│õ\x08▒M®$\x08L\x17ôû\ÝãR\t²\x19╗╩Åõ\x00\x00Ágö&╣\x00ø\x08ï-╣?,\x16L¥.╚í\v▒╚7ð=iÍüPø(┐ô\x04o\x05ù9¤ö\x1EQÞNi╔M\v±\x0E┐B╝\t╠µÃ0"Ïh!©¢\x7FRMÙ░õîª■×µÙ&Kþ¥\vÈëà¢^ÊzÀÂ─■A░ç)÷‗)÷j▒\x13/¤N~║~¯6|Àë╚N£ðlåv"ZDU5ðI\x10ì¾blc/gj»iª\x14═í#ØÉl\x1E╣ým®\x05Ø\e?Ôc´Û{Ûý5oo7é╬&Ø\x10‗ð=‗³└mñêÝ╠¡╚«¯SßK\v{Íôf┬¥Ï\x02Î½e│é▓ø╗╚À+$Ì\x05`▒*│­Y╣,ïc╝j\x7F¡o¢ þy+hÞ\x15\x0F?´1_r╣\x140zE\x10:u&×▀aÔ\x1F\x03F \eÇíH^`Ç▄~y╬Ï\è*(¤9þö<hµf?\x7F\x12ñ■┤╣]ÐFVI╗â╚7D2▓z \x0E+▒³¬½\x07d2n\x14╣\x016¢¢╗╚Ï­¦ç¤_==▓?\x1FÊ >ƒ8G'»[7ËÀ_┤/ô\x01¹■·&y=z¨┌{¬²³éEËRÁ9'w\x1C´ªà╦]º░▀$É(Ñù╦]êóâ┌\x1E┤▒oUAXç╣ùdS¸,▀#¾X\x06ø═.ø┼&\ñGQí\x05 »í╚h─´<ÅQêçNF¹«ÏRK┘\tGS¹▓öG|Ì╗!i \x003L▒ë\x00\x1DWùÉ®ºf\eÓ\x11ºÁt~2┴·tÕ\x1Dï©ë&Êº_^× D{Ã\x11RªY\x13\x04uY\_H?\x18p(2¾O»Ý´▄)¤ã\x15WßÍW¨ùSPË█D‗²¹7ÝA[òòÝ╩¯=òTß;IöFô¼¬¹fÊ¨┤c®ªk±»╬■■7│Ö%Î"ù¦Óün\x01\x05█+@Ë±\x1A^s╣Z1╦&ÁáÍóø;║▄½n═rKÀ┼\x1E‗\x1A}va\x1DKùø╣0ı-\x18jþ╩È·Ðb\x146mÜS║{╦\x17£┼Üµñ║WLy÷ÌƒqD±u│UL\x08°MVè┌▄¥┌¿9XZòÙhö╬%S¼Õz╚[©¦§ÐöÐ²ù9¾├Ê\x07wÚX©ê\x0F+Jï┤\x05ã\x00ÈVLük½╝úhyÐîSı\x19\x05\f─(\v╬Þíı£║ØØ┴\x1D╚Ù\x03°\x7F@Ñvbƒ╬ ╗╣u¬Jºì\x0FOƒ_\x1EE÷²º\§må\x02d│ý.▒Û£WòÞðnı>\x19ñ\x1F¹\x7FrXFQø\x08╬[\x14\x00ËÖ\x12¨ìU¹ªþM?‗?\x1F╝>m*ò£│#\x17Å¢$ó\x10à>à¦<³»▒D╔ùÙ#¨H▓Ó\x0Fr\Jû\x00%╩ÙÊÃ­ëûzµM×¤║'¦Ðº├°Úï\eÒ¦┘çë}Ê‗Z\x17Ú┐║OäÒé\x17cë°╩úa½┤H^Ã¼OÔÒÆ╗û╩╝\x0F/Ä\x17■I‗|É\x18ô¯Õí¸ßÕU´├ï\x13¹3 ╔■­V 2²ÚÞ­\x03é²çZ\x7FÏ7±gá÷ÞO\x7FÈ\x15\x7F\fQ┘\x1F\x0EDøªµÑíHÁ!g=N╚\x7F╦┤\x18¿ì(S°\x01Æ55╬6█ìk#:KD³Z┐û)│\x0EóøƒÉÍ²|uPÓª\x1D¨Óö"MÓ2òÔ╣ì²È¤ÿ_ñ┼¸\fí│à6¢#ö\x0F■[ó¸|QJ\x01A¨èÅmµ¶?6á\e═\x18ÊÕÔË*6\x19║³║/Mvo:╣Á`¶\x17g║±Û­Ø~¬åƒfïÍ└▒?O°┼¶Õ\x7F¾d\x01úù(├á|[¬);¥ÃE─YÖ\x1Dõg¤0«\x13┼Îªñ½║&Áñ╗Jê#R\x13Â¹8±/Ös%"[ƒ°Ï╦\x10VË┴Æ░÷\x1F\x0Eàyfi>0w\v╣┬;±zK/s¾\x7F³$▓Ý©æU]Á)¨╣░║yY,÷ð‗Qà\x1Få<¨H¦\x14{ú¯Dðá¦dç¦Ì¯ÏÕ}pÐº▄\x1F\x14└¯Þ¶T;BJ┼2║²%ËÒ¾ù╚ÕÅØÝ¹È▒#ólôYn\e\x11\x1Dj─▄ª]ò¾y┼\x05)÷\x18Âc¡\x05k\vqnoÝì╩\Ïf§\x00$êª\x19{+■»ôôñ7)Åwï\x07)╚|ï\x17)╚q┼ïöÔ]═·\x15╚÷\x1Dýfÿ'²-+ò/(¥ºÍÊ9\x1FS‗Ð÷Ô÷Ñµ\x1C\e/«ÌÌ<¨ð~┘■È~¢º8Úx´­Þ²Hì××:â7±│úô│y©°p¾õ*·°┴\x0E┐<=v\x7F]ý)³╩Öì┐~█ÄBÑ┐Ã\x1F\x19wÄ­\x16|u╬:°9 Ý¬Ù\x16\‗░¦s>¥x²R?ì¤ÝÎØ\x195ª÷ÖÃ\x15À├DÚ­dztrÏqÚ[Ù$®¿\x13b<;=╣õ´Ëƒú¤»z¡0²¶IK¥<y╗x ÛÝ½├=S<§r-Ê¶Ým╩â\tb¬╬┐┐■ÂÏ´£Á¥Ý\x7FÁ¥-UE_²GGÖêÎX╩tÒyG■jñAÎ¶\x08ÕÆÙSýãN\x16%╗╗[\x159W╦Wíûo▓x$E├D¨÷v¹‗^Tï^<\x7Fô─ÜÅ┘XûWèw\x0F\x03\x12[ë╗î@³å[´?‗Dı▓-╦ÜÕD╠Ô\x15\x13EùÝ,:┼┤ß¶×GE¨╚}\x1AAäg¶­úzB\x16Wïy~ ¾æ\v0°âç%ÁÎ'ÀÀUùF│÷BìF/¾gpÕ*6s\x1F ƒ\x1E¢{■µ¢l╩¶£ã¤c╗╬\x15Ý\x15¹WÏ/,zSV<&º¸Õð┤\x03ÃÉE/ú\x05OÄX╩\eMz;foÑ°\x0E]õ4.#▀òTð\x08Ü╦Ô\x05\x1EM{\x0E\x17æ%¾4Ò.ÐL®Ù¨¯¯yAÒ╣█kÞ\x1A┴▓mmÍ"jàä\x0F┼^ª,¾ûô¸┐╝\x1C{J^8\x15ðÏ*~xç\x0E½f\x11_'═ÑK2ÑQ\x00y¬¤ÂxÿıH┌3×ªê4Ü½└▓¾W.¶┴¼å9\x1EùÆVöí█13¾À_äÆ\x19¶!.®ÿõçtzÒPÍ\x11\x12îi&\x08N åR┬Ã@ÛX&Ó£ë╣Ã´sÑ╝Òyð¾!\td\x13╚v┌Ð\x02~³Iò"mU┤¦³¦╔»>_\x00Õ\x0FÞ\x15╠cfM\e¼r┌═qâÈÅY\x11Ó7É"4▄u[SaÍñI´g\x1Cè·´,\x1Deì¢\f\x19AÆV\x1E:/èÀRÁ:þ|úðÉ®\x1DN\x1C>\x08ßwsÙn░~JÒT\x13┼ê±v░¦¦ƒà─¶─FmÌ}n║╣àb┬ \x17O(Ï¬V▀┘ô¨,>¥rx,ÿ\x14þ\x1AI┤ÉÞ\b¦ÚÚÖ@K\x10\x1CÑ)¶░\=©gË¨\x1EXK;╚ã{t▒┤º©ï▒8ÓP8Ý\x1F°═\x10╠+tú£W\x07\x01vá\x02\x1C{JýR æå<\eË\x15ç2_─ÔcuWì┤JÒÖcÝ-\x7F╗Êuù~ã╦òB\x7Fàå‗·┼B\tEIÉñ/þnìÏ╗E\x1D²`øOé(ÜÁ╝ÿèóïÙm\x0Eq¢ïl½&¡\x08Tú&ôïá¬Ø$Ù·`s¼\x17ÑÙÚÎamı▀OÝ|~¦\x10Õ´i\x14ãø$fÚ4]KÝ ¬\x08\x1EO&H©\x12:_K╩3ûÁ`Î│uG°òk~#▒K¯H\x0E¤2.EIµES$j\x1Eùãıá└9┐«F²³█osUı\x07\x0F╗#sÙ o=`Vc'öR\x06¤\v\v\x06¾┤Û\x12Ñþk\x1D╝F‗\x10ê\x1C e~Û»\t┼p\U»#┴b:ƒ"Ú\x15 eÆKJ┐g┐ú6F =¹Ø\x13æ╦(K©$°ý\x1EÕß3-ò▀~#*Õò`^╩;\x1D{\eÎÇ┼╚\x0E+Z█u~ÍÆØµs‗ÁíS█_\vÁ>ÓèÚ<Æn┤Í\x1DQ\x7FOÃ<Úá║\x1C▄a2╔ÚÕÙGÞÝ2®├?¥©\vCê\e╗øpI&9Z░*s>┘\x1A¥"½/n>Æ®═\x1A¬"■Á§ªóJ¶O╝`®À¿F│&s£½D\eöÕdúýõ╝hj^╠ó¾jÛA ZØ\fÅG÷¤ÃÐ»æ~¾jÞ?32ı\x19·jE\x7F¯╣|¡âı¬zþO\x0EßþËÎ»Þ\x15%÷}\x14´\x04È┼ \x1Eu╚│Ë+\x14· Å¹_─\x03Ý¶/7\x00\x00 ◀"
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34238#issuecomment-550206946 - remove `Accept-Encoding: gzip` from the array of headers if you want to receive a unzipped response, or unzip the response on your own

Comment: In fact, I'm using Expedia API (https://api.ean.com), they're obliging me to introduce "gzip" in header. I tried the solution with gzdecode() and it's not working..

Comment: This is what's displaying in the response : b"\x1F‹\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ŠŽ\x05\x00\x00\x00ÿÿ\x03\x00)»L\x02\x00\x00\x00"